Properties of "false-positive" cases using base 2 for Fermat primality test
Please excuse the nature of this very amateur question - I'm trying to understand the Fermat primality test better by coding it up myself (as least for smaller primes) while attempting to strike a balance between too much trial division of small primes and Fermat testing too many bases :

a ^ (n - 1) ≡ 1 (mod n)

My code right now segments the inputs via this waterfall logic (it only works for n < 4096 for now) -


n < 15 : returns TRUE when it's either (1) n == 2, or (2) odd numbers >= 3, EXCEPT n == 9




Take out all composites of 2, 3, 5, 7 by rephrasing the 8 scenarios of primes (mod 30), thus condensing the trial division of 4 primes to 3 modulo ops :


((n % 30 - 15)^4 % 30 != 16)^(n % 7)
(it's immaterial which division approach one uses here since negatives are no longer a concern) (despite the exponent not appearing boolean in nature, this expression only yields either 0 or 1 numerically and nothing else)


Any n < 143 (11 x 13) is prime, EXCEPT n == 121 (11 x 11)




n < 1024 : returns TRUE when base-2 Fermat primality test yields a congruence of 1, EXCEPT n == 341 (the smallest base-2 Fermat pseudoprime)




Everyone else : returns TRUE when base-2 Fermat primality test yields a congruence of 1, AND not a composite of 23


For inputs n < 4096, the above waterfall logic yielded 4 base-2 Fermat pseudoprimes :
 1  1,387:  19   73    <—— 4x
 2  2,701:  37   73    <—— 2x
 3  3,277:  29  113    <—— 4x
 4  4,033:  37  109    <—— 3x

Can someone help me understand why the 4 pseudoprimes all share this interesting property :

The larger prime factor is the largest prime less than either 2x, 3x, or 4x that of the smaller prime factor

If I haven't taken out composites of 23, then 2,047 would also show up with the same property (and a "ratio" of 4x between the prime factors)
Thanks a lot for your help.

You should collect more "empirical evidence" to make that conjecture.

@Prem : I never declared it was a conjecture, but merely an observation stemming from a very small range of numbers.

To look at one concrete scenario, suppose you have primes $p = k+1$ and $q = 2k+1$. This is happening in the $(37,73)$ case.
Then we have $2^{k} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $2^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod q$, by Fermat's little theorem. Since $q \mid (2^{2k}-1)$ and this factors as $(2^k+1)(2^k-1)$, we must have either $q\mid (2^k+1)$ or $q\mid (2^k-1)$. Intuitively, about half the time, we'll get lucky and $q \mid (2^k-1)$, which means that $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod q$.
Putting together $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod q$, we conclude $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$. Therefore $$2^{pq-1} = 2^{2k^2 + 3k} = (2^k)^{2k+3} \equiv 1^{2k+3} = 1 \pmod{pq}$$ and we conclude that $pq$ is a false positive for the base $2$ Fermat primality test.
The step in bold does happen roughly half the time; for $p \le 1\,000\,000$, there's $7752$ cases where both $p$ and $2p-1$ are prime, and $p(2p-1)$ is a false positive in $3817$ of those cases.

The pairs $(19,73)$ and $(29,113)$ are pairs of primes of the form $(k+1,4k+1)$. The same logic can be used there, except that we want to go from $2^{4k} \equiv 1\pmod q$ to $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod q$. I'm not super sure what happens here; we'd expect $2^k$ to be equally likely to be any of four values modulo $q$ (since by quadratic reciprocity $-1$ is a quadratic residue here). Experimentally, though, we get a pseudoprime about half the time from this scenario, not a quarter of the time.
The pair $(37,109)$ has the form $(k+1,3k+1)$. Here, we want to go from $2^{3k} \equiv 1 \pmod q$ to $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod q$. Here, $2^k$ is the right cube root of $1$ modulo $q$ about a third of the time, which we can verify experimentally.
Later on, we'll get more pseudoprimes along these lines; for example, $4681 = 31 \cdot 151$, which is a pair of primes of the form $(k+1,5k+1)$.

So are there any approaches you recommend for dealing with these specific types of composites (other than testing more bases) ? Or perhaps, are certain bases more effective in rooting out these Fermat pseudoprimes ? I'm trying to avoid having to hard-code in those 3817 false-positive cases you mentioned

I think you're at the point where, rather than squeeze out a bit more power from the Fermat primality test, you should consider an extension of it such as Miller–Rabin or Solovay–Strassen. The basic setup is common between the three tests - you're computing large powers of $2$ (or some other base) modulo the candidate prime. Miller's version will probably be easier for you; for Solovay–Strassen, you'd need to learn a bit about Jacobi symbols.

@Misha Lavrov : so I took your advice, did a massive reworking of the algorithm, postponed the mutli-small prime filter until n > 2048, and also found a clean way to do just Fermat base-2 test for n <= 8192 without needing to do trial division on too many small primes, and only switch to Miller-Rabin for n > 8192. And by leveraging a unique property about floating point data types, even without using a big-int library or any pre-made lookup tables, my function now could give a definitive answer on primality of all n <= 1024 using a max of just 2 modulo ops (inc. handling false pos)
